# What does this Java statement mean?

Tags: java

```
boolean rhs;  
rhs = value == null;
```

Specifically, the part I don't understand is the = operator followed by value followed by ==.
What does that mean?

Comment: if value equal to null assign true/false to rhs

Comment: Look for "operator precedence", and you will understand that statement.

Comment: Think of it like `if (value == null) rhs = true; else rhs = false`, but just shorter...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since comparing `==` has [higher priority](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than `=` assigning, code

```
rhs = value == null;
```

is the same as

```
rhs = (value == null);
```

So it will check if `value` is `null` and store result of that test in `rhs`.

Answer (score 3):

`value == null` is a boolean expression which evaluates to `true` if `value == null`, otherwise it is `false`. The value of this expression is assigned to `rhs`

The 2 statements are equivalent to

```
boolean rhs;
if (value == null)
   rhs = true;
else
   rhs false;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is **assigning** to the boolean variable `rhs` the result of **evaluating**: `value == null`

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way to check whether the the `value` is `null` or not. If `null` then is will assign `true` to `rhs`, else `false`. You can try it by your self using following code:

```
    String value = null;
    String value2 = "Testing";
    boolean rhs;
    System.out.println(rhs=value == null); //print true
    System.out.println(rhs);

    System.out.println(rhs=value2 == null);//print false
    System.out.println(rhs);
```